# Same HTML ID "h-related-tags" used twice in same page: for "stats module" and "related tags" sidebar modules

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, design, userscript

A userscript I've been working on enhances the Related Tags and similar "modules" in the Stack Exchange sidebar on the right side of each page.

When I noticed it wasn't modifying the Related Tags on [a "tag info" page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/augeas/info) I investigated and found that though I was looking for the correct ID for that module, that the same ID was incorrectly used for the Stats module on the same page.

Naturally this means `document.getElementById()` and any jQuery which calls it will only get the first element with this ID, which in my case is the wrong one.

The Stats module should have some unique ID such as `h-stats` etc.

Here's the relevant HTML for each module with the IDs pointed out in HTML comments:

Stats module HTML:

```
<div class="module">
    <h4 id="h-related-tags">Stats</h4>
    <!--   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         --> 
    <table id="qinfo">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><p class="label-key">created</p></td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px"><p class="label-key" title="2012-08-01 09:38:15Z"><b>3 months ago</b></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="label-key">viewed</p></td>

            <td style="padding-left:10px"><p class="label-key"><b>4 times</b></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="label-key">active</p></td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px"><p class="label-key"><b>3 months ago</b></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="label-key">editors</p></td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px"><p class="label-key"><b>1</b></p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>

</div>
```

Related Tags module HTML:

```
<div class="module">

<h4 id="h-related-tags">Related Tags</h4>
<!--    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                -->
            <a href="/tags/puppet/info" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">puppet</a>&nbsp;<span class="item-multiplier"><span class="item-multiplier-x">×</span>&nbsp;<span class="item-multiplier-count">3</span></span><br>
            <a href="/tags/ruby/info" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">ruby</a>&nbsp;<br>
            <a href="/tags/gem/info" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">gem</a>&nbsp;<br>
            <a href="/tags/configuration/info" class="post-tag" title="" rel="tag">configuration</a>&nbsp;<br>
            <a href="/tags/regex/info" class="post-tag" title="tag wiki for 'regex'" rel="tag">regex</a>&nbsp;<br>


<br>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to close as off topic thinking it's programming question, then after second read realized the real meaning. Hopefully adding the [meta-tag:userscript] tag will help others to avoid falling into the same trap. :)

Comment: Feel free to retag as you think is best, I don't know the ropes here on meta as well as on my usual sites.

Comment: Already done before posting the comment. You seem to be just fine with the ropes here! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently that used to be there for a reason (a bad CSS-y reason, but a reason), but it's completely pointless now.

It will be fixed in the next build.